# Dependent Types: Template argument deduction failed

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-inference

In my code I use a templated image class `Image<T>` in combination with `std::shared_ptr`. These image pointers are supposed to be passed to various image processing functions, some of which are independent of the image type. Consider the following definition of `Image<T>`, and two processing functions `function1()` and `function2()`.

```
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
struct Image
{
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Image<T>> Ptr;
};

template <typename T>
void function1 (typename Image<T>::Ptr image) {}

template <typename T>
void function2 (std::shared_ptr<Image<T>> image) {}
```

While `function1()` and `function2()` effectively have the same signature, `function1()` is easier to read and hides the details of how the pointer is realized. However, I am having trouble calling `function1()` without explicitly specifying the template type. Consider the following code:

```
int main (void)
{
    Image<int>::Ptr image = std::make_shared<Image<int>>();
    function1(image);       // Does NOT compile
    function1<int>(image);  // Does compile
    function2(image);       // Does compile
    return 0;
}
```

Where the first call leads to the compile error:

```
example.cc: In function 'int main()':
example.cc:18:19: error: no matching function for call to 'function1(MyClass<int>::Ptr&)'
example.cc:18:19: note: candidate is:
example.cc:10:6: note: template<class T> void function1(typename MyClass<T>::Ptr)
example.cc:10:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
example.cc:18:19: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
```

My question is the following: Is it possible to use the signature of `function1()` without having to manually specify the template argument? What is causing the compiler error?

I suspect the problem is caused by the fact that `Image<T>::Ptr` is a dependent type. Thus the compiler cannot know the exact definition of this field at compile time. Is it possible to tell the compiler there will be no specializations of this field, in the spirit of the `typename` keyword which tells the compiler that a field is a type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is causing the compiler error?

You're (solely) using `T` in a non-deduced context: *nested-name-specifier*s. That is, you put `T` inside a name that merely specifies where the type lies within. The compiler cannot understand your actual intention and would have to try a lot of `T`'s.

> Is it possible to use the signature of `function1()` without having to manually specify the template argument?

Not really. If you want a more concise way of referring to a smart pointer to an Image, you can use an alias template though:

```
template <typename T>
using ImagePtr = std::shared_ptr<Image<T>>;
```

And write `function1` thusly:

```
template <typename U>
void function1(ImagePtr<U> p) {}
```