# Template argument deduction failed with typedef?

Tags: c++, class, templates, typedef

Considering the following couple of classes:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class A{ 
public:
    // ...
};

template<typename _T>
struct alias { typedef A<int,_T> intA; };

class B{
public:
    // ...
    template <typename _T> B& operator=(const typename alias<_T>::intA& _arg) { };
};
```

When I try to assign an object of class `A<int,int>` to an object of class `B`, I get the following compilation error:

`template argument deduction/substitution failed:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘_T’`

Is there an alternative way to use something of a typedef as the input argument to  `B::operator=()`??

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_T`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

templated `using` might fix the issue

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class A{ 
public:
    // ...
};

template<typename _T>
using alias = A<int,_T>;

class B{
public:
    // ...
    template <typename _T> B& operator=(const alias<_T>& ) { return *this; };
};

void f()
{
    B b;
    A<int, int> a;
    b = a;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `intA` is a dependant name. Templates cannot be deduced from dependant names. See for example: [Dependent Types: Template argument deduction failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31541008/dependent-types-template-argument-deduction-failed).

You are also missing the `typename` keyword.

You can either explicitly specify the type for the operator:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct A{ };

template<typename _T>
struct alias { typedef A<int,_T> intA; };

struct B 
{
    template <typename T> B& operator=(const typename alias<T>::intA& _arg) { };
};

int main() 
{
    A<int,int> a;
    B b;
    b.operator=<int>(a);
    return 0;
}
```

or you can have a specific, non-dependant-name parameter using a templated alias (with or without a function):

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct A{ };

template<class T>
using alias_int = A<int, T>;

struct alias
{
    template<class T>
    using intA = A<int, T>;
};

struct B 
{
    template <typename T> B& operator=(const alias_int<T>& _arg) { };
};

struct C
{
    template <typename T> C& operator=(const alias::intA<T>& _arg) { };
};

int main() 
{
    A<int,int> a;
    B b;
    C c;
    b = a;
    c = a;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a different error (using g++ 5.4):
`need ‘typename’ before ‘alias<_T>::intA’ because ‘alias<_T>’ is a dependent scope`
and true enough the following compiles for me:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class A{ 
public:
    // ...
};

template<typename _T>
struct alias { typedef A<int,_T> intA; };

class B{
public:
    // ...
    template <typename _T> B& operator=(const typename alias<_T>::intA& _arg) { };
};
```

I think the reason is that `alias<_T>::intA` isn't an actual type but a templated typename.

Comment: I forgot the `typename` keyword on my code sample. I'm attemping to compile with `-std=c++11` if that's relevant.

Comment: Compiles for me with -std=c++11.